# How to clear only some texture in opengl

Tags: ios5, opengl-es

Suppose I have made five strokes with different texture in opengl.Now I want to clear all only four texture I want to keep as it is remaining one texture.How can I do that.
When I use glClear() it removes all.I can not use glScissor as texture location can be same.
How can I do this.

Comment: You can't really 'erase' a layer off the top of the framebuffer. Instead of erasing some texture stroke, you should figure out how to clear the frame, an then redraw everything else but the stroke you don't want. OpenGL isn't photoshop, it can't remember what's underneath something when you draw over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create exact texture with:

```
GLuint index=x;
glGenTextures(1, &index);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, index);
glTexImage2D...
```

And delete the same texture with:

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &index);
```

Now, you don't need to delete texture during the rendering process, just use the proper texture index for desired stroke. Use the same mesh, just change the texture index when rendering vertices.

Comment: No I am not asking about delete texture.I mean to say I do not want to clear whole framebuffer.I need to clear part of framebuufer.I need in your case the an image render using texture at index needs to be preserve even after glclear